# Error in Stack Exchange tag-subscription email

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, email

I subscribed to the Ruby on Rails tag, and in the email I received [one of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721058/undefined-method-merge-for-2fixnum) has caused some kind of strange display error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. The bug was that we were sending the entire body of the email through a Markdown parser, even though question titles don't contain Markdown. So, any Markdown syntax (a backtick in this case) in the question title would have caused undesired behavior. The fix was to [backslash-escape special characters](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) in question titles.

(Thanks for the debugging help, @[badp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75346/error-in-stack-exchange-tag-subscription-email/75347#75347).)

Answer (score 2):

The question title is:

> undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

The post contains the following line:

> undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

The Markdown parser notices the pair of backticks and applies a `<code>` tag on everything in the middle. :)

I guess malformed markdown is to blame, because I cannot reproduce the issue from the site:

> #### undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum
>
> undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

Comment: Yea, I assumed it was something along those lines with the dangling `</h3>`