# Superfluous slash before comma in stackexchange.com emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, email-notification, tag-filters

I found a superfluous backslash symbol (\) before the comma symbol in my tag set emails from stackexchange.com. For example, one of the questions has the following title:

[iPhone app's Core Data\, after upgrade to App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909288/iphone-apps-core-data-after-upgrade-to-app-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chalk another one up for regular expressions: we weren't backslash-escaping "-" in our regex for [escaping markdown characters in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75346/error-in-stack-exchange-tag-subscription-email/77404#77404). This is fixed now.